# Discord.py not being detected in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord.py

I had installed discord.py in cmd like so,  `pip install discord.py`, but whenever I type `import discord` in vscode, It doesnt seem to detect it and gives the error "Import "discord" could not be resolved". I also made a new terminal in vscode and typed in `pip install discord.py`, and it said that all requirements were fulfilled! How can I import and use discord in vscode??

Comment: Sometimes you have to tell VS Code which Python interpreter you want to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install the required modules in the currently selected environment:
(You could use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VSCode terminal, it will automatically enter the current Python environment)

Please check the source of the installation tool pip, the module is installed here:

[image]

Run:

[image]

check:

[image]

Reference: [discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/) and [environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).